# Sending objects through sockets

Tags: java, xml, sockets, serialization, network-programming

The only socket programming I have done in the past is simple text streams. I am wondering what is the most effective way to send something like a Java object through a socket.

For instance if I have the following Employee class (Dependent would be a simple class composed of a dependent's information):

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    private ArrayList<Dependent> dependents;
}
```

Should I just make the Employee object Serializable and send instances through the socket. Or should I write up an xml file containing the Employees information and send that? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Or is there some completely different and better way? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only sending data betwen Java JVMs, then either choice is possible.

A textual representation (XML, JSON, or custom) has several advantages:

- it's easier to make it interoperable between Java and other languages
- it's less brittle in the face of version changes or slightly different versions of your code at each end of the socket
- it's vastly easier to test and debug

Depending on the format, it may be a little slower, but this often not significant.

Comment: I've heard, that JSON coding is faster than serialization, but JSON decoding is slower than deserialization

Answer (score 3):

If you are not necessarily tied to using XML you could also try JSON. The [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library makes this very trivial. To serialise the code it is as simple as:-

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
...

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(employee);
```

And to deserialise the `String` at the other end:-

```
String socketDataAsString = null;
...<read from socket>...

Gson gson = new Gson();
Employee employee = gson.fromJson(socketDataAsString, Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must directly use low level sockets, there are a couple of ways you could to it. You  could convert it to a text format and send the bytes and then reconstruct it on the other side. If your objects are serializable, you can send them over the socket (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0043.html).

If you have some flexibility, you could use RMI to interact remotely as well.

Comment: Jeff, what is use of RMI in this particular case?