# Send a Data Record through TCP in java

Tags: java, delphi, tcp, records

I'm a Delphi developer and recently I decided to port one of my programs to java and I'm doing the server side program in java to make it cross-platform.

In Delphi, I could easily send a record as an array of bytes through TCP but I don't have much experience in java and I have no idea how to do it in an easy but moderated way. 
Here is a sample of my data record:

```
type
  Tlogin = record
    username : string[50];
    password : string[50];
    version  : word;
  end;
```

And I would just simply send this type of record after making it an array of bytes.

Any ideas how to make such data records in java and how do I set size for strings, or any better suggestions to handle strings for sending them through TCP.

Comment: "any better suggestions to handle strings for sending them through TCP?". Yes, XML, JSON, or a web service, as was suggested by answers to your previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633951/how-to-handle-a-serialized-object-sent-by-java-over-tcp). Why the specific requirement to serialize the data?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you simply send objects over the sockets between a client and server and there are a number of ways to do that. For a related reference please visit

[Sending objects over Java sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404779/sending-objects-through-sockets)

For a more step by step example visit the following link:

[JGuru - Sending objects over a socket](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=10472)

In your case your object would look as follows

```
class TLogin implements Serializable
{

   private String userName;
   private String password;
   private int version;

   //implement your objects methods below


}
```

Fields within the object that you do not want to participate in serialization and de-serialization can be marked as **transient**

For a detailed step by step example of serialization visit
[Java Serialization Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Edit based on the comment provided to my earlier response.

Serialization in simple words : It is a technique where-in a Java object is converted to a byte sequence (essentially, all fields of the object except those marked transient are a part of this byte sequence). This byte sequence can then be used to re-construct the object at a later point of time. The byte sequence obtained by serializing an object can be either persisted to a store or transmitted over a network channel, in order to have it re-construct the object at a later stage.
Serialization is at the core of a lot of communication protocols that happen within a client server environment within Java using either of RMI, Sockets or SOAP.

Having talked about serialization , we come to the client-server problem.
In case, the plan is only to port the server side code to Java then you have the following options to enable communication between the client and server:

1. Design the server to use SOAP/REST to communicate with the Delphi client.
2. Augment your record with a header data structure that contains information about the length and type of the data being stored and use this header within the client transmitted byte sequence on the server side to re-construct the object.

However, in my opinion the first method is better than the second since

1. it is a standard inter-operable technique.If at a later point of time you wish to port the client to some other language like C# or Python, you do not need to change the server.
2. it lets the web service infrastructure handle the nitty gritty of
   SOAP/REST serialization and lets you focus on the business logic

I hope this lengthy answer points you in a direction towards the solution

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but what does this serializing actually do to the data? because my client application is written in delphi and im only planning to port my server to java. in delphi i need to know the size of string in order to read and put it in the data variable, in java it seem to be done automatically but in delphi it is not