# How to handle a serialized object sent by java over tcp

Tags: java, delphi

my server application is on java and my client is on delphi, so i need to send an serialized object from java to my client and put the received data in a record like this:

in java

```
 class Login implements Serializable
 {
    public String userName;
    public String password;
    public int version;
 }
```

in delphi

```
   type
    login = record
     username : string;
     password : string;
     version  : integer;
    end;
```

The problem is i dont know how java serialize an object so i can put the values on my record.

Comment: To serialize between languages, you have to find a form of serialization which works in Java and Delphi.  If you can't find one, you can write your own. `Serializable` is only usable in a JVM language.

Answer (score 4):

Serialization is only useful when you have a JVM doing both the serialization and deserialization.

In most other cases you would be better of with a transport format designed for this.  I would suggest looking into a simple XML format for this, or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can send the object in JSON format using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library and then parse it in delphi side.

Answer (score 0):

Check the serializable information for java.  your best option here might be to implement a custom your on inpl of the serialization. and as suggested by Thorbjorn use something like JSON as the output format.